# How to know if Invoke was called in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have an event Action Event in my code.

where I put many events there like this:

```
  public class TheClass 
  {
        public static Action Event;
    
        public TheClass() {
            // dummy example but many others methods could be registerd here 
            //even outside this class because it is static
            TheClass.Event += myMethod;
        }
    
        public void myMethod() {
            // dummy example
        }

        public void DoInvokeTest() {
            Event.Invoke(); // here I'd like to know if my method was invoked and what object that this method is being launched.
            // here I want to know the method called in which object
        }
}
```

How to know if myMethod was called and by what object that this method is being launched.
e.g. on Event.Invoke()

there is an object: theclassObj.myMethod which the method is called, so I want to know that this method was called in this object 'theclassObj'.

Comment: When you say "by who", what exactly do you mean? That's going to affect the answer a lot.

Comment: by who means: what's the object the method is called in, I'll change the description

Comment: Does this info help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information

Comment: The whole point of an event is that it doesn't need to care what objects or methods are added as event handlers.  Writing code that *would* care about it is highly suspicious and is in indication of a more fundamental design problem.

Comment: @Servy maybe you right, I just want to know if the event was consumed becuase of network. Imagine an event comming from net and could not be consumed at that moment should be cached for later consumption.

Comment: @felipe If it's possible for the thing that triggers the event to happen before the event handler is added, then yeah, you shouldn't be using an event, you need to use something that stores the information more permanently.  If you want to use an event you need to have some way of ensuring that the event handler is added before you start whatever network actions could fire the event.  If that's feasible, and event is fine, but then you no longer need the ability to inspect the handlers from within this class.